# JWKS URL input is disabled in KeyCloak when the Use JWKS URL switch is on

Tags: jwt, keycloak

When I was following the KeyCloak official doc (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#client-authentication-with-signed-jwt) to configure "Signed Jwt" as the Client Authenticator,the JWKS URL input is read only after I made the configuration changes according to the document:

[image: The Settings tab]

[image: The Credentials tab]

[image: The Keys tab]

The grey text area under the "Use JWKS URL" switch is read only.

KeyCloak Version: 19.0.3

Any step did I miss or anything else I need do to enable input JWKS URL for this client?